# Opencart 2.3.0.2 Grid description length

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

anyone know how to truncate/limit the text output of the description for `Opencart 2.3` category description length?

I'm looking at this :

```
<p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
```

With no idea what to do with it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want to limit the string to an n amount of characters you can use `substr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in-built function/method to do that. You can add a custom method for that purpose in the `Product Controller` or you can do it straight in the `Template` file.

Method:

```
function shortenText($text, $count=10) {            
        $words = array_chunk(explode(' ', $text), $count);
        $shortText =  implode($separator, $words[0]);
        return $shortText;
    }
```

Replace:

If putting the above in template:

```
<p><?php echo shortenText($product['description'],15); ?></p>
```

If Putting in Controller:

```
'description' => $this->shortenText($product_data['description'],15);
```

Or Refer: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=43484

Comment: Perfect, thankyou very much! :D worked out great, i used the "template" method, was simple to setup. Thanks again!